# Memory leak with dynamic code in COM Interop

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, asp-classic, memory-leaks, com-interop

For compatibility reasons between out legacy ASP code and new ASP.NET code, we have a bunch of .NET COM object that expose some of our .NET utilities to the ASP. In some cases we need to work with another COM objects inside of our .NET COM wrappers. To allow high flexibility and avoid PIA dependencies, we decided to use dynamic code to work with those COM objects.

Simplified C# COM object:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCom
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("6DC92920-8C3C-4C81-A615-BD0E3A332024")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface ITestComObject
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string MyMethod(dynamic dictionary);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("F52A463E-F03B-4703-860C-E86CDD6D04E3")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("TestCom.TestComObject")]
    public class TestComObject : ITestComObject
    {
        string ITestComObject.MyMethod(dynamic dictionary)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (dictionary != null)
            {
                foreach (object key in dictionary)
                {
                    object p = dictionary[key];
                    if (p != null)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}{2}", key, p, Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Test ASP Page:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
    Dim testObj, params
    Set testObj = Server.CreateObject("TestCom.TestComObject")

    Set params = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    params("lang") = "en-US"
    params("num") = 42

    Response.Write testObj.MyMethod(params)

    Set testObj = Nothing
    Set params = Nothing
%>
```

In normal case, the dynamic code would compile just once and subsequent calls would reuse it. However in our case it seems that the dynamic code is compiled on every single call. When i attach a memory profiler to IIS process i can clearly see additional objects from Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics namespace appearing in gen2. This effectively causes a memory leak in our IIS process.

Any ideas how to fix this dynamic code compilation issue? Please note that rewriting all code to use PIA and COM interfaces is not always an option in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put any code which is susceptible to memory leak as a separate process - parent process communicate with such leaky processses via socket for instance. Then either freshly kick starts these leaky process on every call, or restarts them sometime during the evening!

Comment: norm: Your suggestion is not really valid in our case with ASP and COM Interop. Also i don't think that ignoring the memory leak and just restarting a process is acceptable on a principle.